# Plugin not displayed on Plugins Section

Tags: plugins, plugin-sproutforms

I'm trying to install Sprout Report plugin, so I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-reports)
so I followed the instructions from the plugin documentation site: [here](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/reports/installing-and-updating-craft-2.html#requirements)

According to that documentation the zip folder from GitHub just need to be placed on craft/plugins folder but after I do this the plugin still does not show on dashboard.

Do I have to do something else so it can be displayed?

Also the zip file from GitHub gives me a folder name: **craft-sprout-reports-1** but according to the official documentation the plugin folder's name should be named as: **sproutreports**

Will be the name of the folder the reason why it's not showing?

Thanks for any help.

## plugin-sproutreports

## plugin-sproutforms

Comment: What Craft version do you use?

Comment: the current version of my craft is 2.7.2

Comment: The plugin in the link is for the Craft 3 version of the cms. Make sure to change to the correct branch to download the Craft 2 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When downloading from the Github releases tab be sure that you are downloading the latest plugin release for the version of Craft you are using.

In the case of Sprout Reports:

- v0.x releases are for Craft 2
- v1.x releases are for Craft 3

When in doubt you can look at the files within the plugin folder and try to determine which version of Craft the plugin is for. Most Craft 3 plugins will have a composer.json file and `src/` folder.

Comment: you were right! I had downloaded one totally different for my craft version. I got this one https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-reports/releases.
Now to get the entries on my contact form im creating a new custom query report. if I do this: select * from craft_sproutformscontent_contact I only get 40 records from 219 in total. why? thanks for ur help

Comment: This should be opened as a separate question. Sprout Forms provides a Sprout Forms Entries report that you can select from the New Report dropdown once both Sprout Forms is installed. That should provide the report you are looking for without needing a custom query. Custom Queries can get very complicated when querying elements as there are a lot of potential relationships in the database tables. It's much easier to build a custom Data Source and use Craft's API via PHP to build reports querying elements: https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/reports/custom-data-sources.html